# $.cookie в jQuery: не получается сохранить случайные значения

Tags: jquery, cookie

Вот этот код нормально работает и при каждой перезагрузке страницы выдает новые три случайных элемента массива.

```
var arr = [ тут куча элементов массива ];

function selfRandom(min, max)
{
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var n1 = selfRandom(0, arr.length-1);
var n2 = selfRandom(0, n1-1);
var n3 = selfRandom(n1+1, arr.length-1);

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div#text').text(arr[n1] + ", " + arr[n2] + " и " + arr[n3] + ".");
});
```

Но мне надо, чтобы выбор трех случайных элементов производился раз в сутки. И вот этот код уже не работает:

```
var arr = [ тут куча элементов массива ];

function selfRandom(min, max)
{
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var n1 = selfRandom(0, arr.length-1);
var n2 = selfRandom(0, n1-1);
var n3 = selfRandom(n1+1, arr.length-1);

$.cookie('num1', n1);
$.cookie('num2', n2);
$.cookie('num3', n3);

var r1 = $.cookie('num1');
var r2 = $.cookie('num2');
var r3 = $.cookie('num3');    

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div#text').text(arr[r1] + ", " + arr[r2] + " и " + arr[r3] + ".");
});
```

Нужный текст (три элемента массива) на страничке вообще не появляется.

В чем ошибка и как ее исправить?